# PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest producing a 422 unprocessable entity?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am running the command on Windows 10 in powershell.

The command is as follows

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri www.example.com -Method POST -InFile FileNameHere
```

and the error I'm getting is

```
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "www.example.com ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest]，WebExce
    ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I'm a beginner so I don't know whats going on exactly...

Comment: what is the content of "FileNameHere"? what are you trying to achieve? i had issues using the POST method when i did not specify the content type like `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri www.example.com -Method POST -InFile FileNameHere -ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a value for `-ContentType`.
e.g.,

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri www.example.com -Method POST -ContentType 'text/plain' -InFile FileNameHere
```